# Is it possible to change FloatingActionButton size at runtime programatically?

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

I am using [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#attr_android.support.design:fabSize) from support library. I noticed that size can only be changed in the XML using the attribute **app:fab_size=""**.

I looked at the source code and there are no methods that would allow to change the fab size when app is running.

I simply want to change fab's size between **MINI** and **NORMAL** based on the user input, so I need to do it programatically.

Has anyone find a way to do this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Size is determined upon `FloatingActionButton` creation and remains static during its lifecycle. There are no public methods that allow to change the size dynamically. Of course you could use `java reflection` in order to access private `size` and `padding` fields and change them, but that's `not a good` idea. Alternatively, you can take a look at some 3rd party implementation, which allows changing button's size dynamically, this [one](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) for example

Answer (score 9):

I think `FloatingActionButton` `setSize()` method does what you want. If you have a `FloatingActionButton` called `fab`, you can use:

```
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setCustomSize(), this method just changes the customSize property, so you have to requestLayout after changing customSize.

```
public void setCustomSize(@Px int size) {
    if (size < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Custom size must be non-negative");
    } else {
        this.customSize = size;
    }
}
```

below code should change the size.

```
fab.setCustomSize(size);
fab.requestLayout();
```